# A typo on "Set a bounty on a question" privilege description page

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, privileges-page

Privilege: [Set a bounty on a question](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

Section: *When does a bounty expire?*

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period
>   ending, half the bounty value will be automatically **be** awarded to the
>   top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a
>   score of at least 2.

I guess the *be* in bold is extra.

Comment: This was actually [fixed a while ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/66248/revisions), but it seems that the update was never pushed out to the rest of the sites...